# How to get a bit from a byte without bitwise operations

Tags: byte

i want to know if there's a way to get a specific bit from a byte, without bitwise operators.

I think i've got a clue, i imagine a way to do it with square root or power... and mod.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: You can easily use mod to get the least significant bit and you can use division to rotate any bit to the least significant bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using Python:

```
>>> def getbit(i, n):
...     return i // 2 ** n % 2
... 
>>> for i in range(8): print(f"Bit {i}: {getbit(0b10101111, i)}")
... 
Bit 0: 1
Bit 1: 1
Bit 2: 1
Bit 3: 1
Bit 4: 0
Bit 5: 1
Bit 6: 0
Bit 7: 1
```